# How to preserve white spaces in content editable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am using the content editable div as a field to fetch user inputs in my website.
But my problem is that when i get the contents of the div using jquery all the white spaces are lost which are entered by the user in the div ?

So, I want to know is there any way to preserve all the white spaces for content editable div ?

Thanks

Comment: CSS property `white-space: pre` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Comment: white-space: pre is not working while fetching the value of div using jquery...my browser is chrome

Comment: `white=space` or `white-space`?

Comment: You should accept @iamio's answer. It also fixes a strange behavior in Firefox where typed spaces at the end of an editable `div` collapses.

Answer (score 35):

I found the answer here: http://simonewebdesign.it/blog/how-to-make-browser-editor-with-html5-contenteditable/

Your css style for the content-editable element should contain the following:

```
.content_editable_element {
    white-space: pre-wrap;       /* css-3 */
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
    white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
    word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
}
```

Comment: Using `white-space: pre;` also works as well as preventing text from wrapping

Answer (score 1):

div has a default white-space: normal;. How is it gone anyway and how do you get/fetch the contents? I think line-breaks will also be a problem

```
<div class="input" contenteditable="true">abc 123 def 456</div>
<button class="get">get</button>   
$('.get').click(function(){alert($('.editable').text());});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mark_s/3Th8r/)