# CKEditor is omitting spaces in IE and FF

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, ckeditor, contenteditable

i have configured CKEditor inside jQueryUI dialogue box text area

**In Firefox and IE :**

- **case 1**: when i enter "sometext+space" it returns only "sometext" . space is omitted .
- **case 2**: "sometext+space+space" it
  returns only "sometext+space" . here more than one spaces are converted to
  single . like wise if i enter 3 spaces , 4 spaces .only one space is
  returning .

in Google Chrome it is working fine.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What's the question the you want to ask?

Comment: in browsers like  FF and IE spaces are omitted .In google chrome what ever i entered in ckeditor textarea it is returning perfectly.but in Firefox & IE problem occurs .  Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide a demo page that shows the problem happening? CKEditor works well for most of us, so there is likely to be something specific on your site that is causing this issue, but without seeing the site in action, it's not going to be easy for anyone to guess the cause of it.

Comment: this link may help you  -  http://jsfiddle.net/Ravi_SPS/pBL5G/2/   .     issue occurs in Firefox & IE .  Google chrome it is working fine . just insert a text  with space at the end and see . space will be omitted in FF & IE

Comment: How are you reading the value from ckeditor?

Comment: var editor = $('textarea.editor').ckeditorGet();
var data = editor.getData();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a behaviour controlled by browser and CKEditor has nothing to do with it.

Fact is: how can be a space at the end of block represented in HTML? There's only one way when we are not using pre formatted block:

```
<p>Hello&nbsp;</p>
```

So when you press space at the end of a block you expect this HTML to be created underneath. And this is what Chrome and Safari do.

However, next you start typing another word. If browsers would just insert these next characters you would end up with:

```
<p>Hello&nbsp;World!</p>
```

But wait a minute... you wanted a normal, breakable space between these words, right? Therefore Chrome and Safari replace these `&nbsp;` with a normal space when you continue typing... unless they lose a context. And then you may end up with lots of `&nbsp;`s which is a problem.

Therefore, IE and FF do this differently. When you press a space they cheat and insert a normal space (or perhaps even nothing – I didn't check) and render it. This is kind of a cheat, because this normal space would not be visible if you would render this content outside of `contentEditable`. This is what you encountered and I'm afraid there's no easy solution to that problem. You just have to live with it.

There's one trick, though, which you could try, but it'd be pretty hard to implement. First, style your content as explained in [How to preserve white spaces in content editable div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19647290/how-to-preserve-white-spaces-in-content-editable-div). Then, change [CKEditor's parser](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.htmlParser), so it does not drop whitespaces at block boundaries. The second step is the toughest, because it will require CKEditor's code modification.

Comment: CKEditor's code modification.but how ? because ckeditor gives only source codes for plugins .

Comment: Full code source is available – https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev. See the README to learn how to build and minified it.