# Text doesn't pass to a second line in contenteditable div

Tags: html, css

Problem occurs when I am using `white-space: pre;` css style to preserve white spaces in content editable div ([How to preserve white spaces in content editable div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19647290/how-to-preserve-white-spaces-in-content-editable-div)).

When I type something in `contenteditable div` and input text hits the right border of `contenteditable div`, text doesn't pass to a second line it keeps on staying on a first line thus text horizontally overflows a `contenteditable div`.

How to force a text to pass to the next line when it hits to the right border of `contenteditable div`? Thanks!

code: https://jsfiddle.net/zozd65uq/2/

Comment: Please post a [mcve] in your question. I can't replicate your issue with the most basic of examples https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/0nybkkt9/

Comment: @Pete my code: https://jsfiddle.net/zozd65uq/2/

Comment: @j08691 my code: [code](http://jsfiddle.net/zozd65uq/2)

Comment: Perhaps you missed the part of my question that said **"in your question"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `white-space: pre` to `pre-wrap` and your text will wrap.

`white-space: pre` means white-spaces are preserved in the text and lines won't wrap onto the next line unless you add a carriage return or `<br>`

```css
#ediv {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    height: 60%;
    width: 50%;
    color: black;
    border: 1px solid #C0CAD5;
    padding: 3px 25px 3px 3px;
    cursor: text;
}
```

```html
<div id='ediv' contenteditable='true'>
  
</div>
```

[More information on `white-space` css](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)

Answer (score -1):

This is because you have mentioned width and height of that div. That fix the div on the page and you text can't be visible outside of the boundaries of div tag.

I have two example. First one work and the second one will be like yours.
**1**

```
<div contenteditable="true">This is a paragraph. It is editable. Try to change this text.</div>

</body>
```

**2**

```
  <html>
    <body>

    <div contenteditable="true" style="width:100px;height:100px;">This is a paragraph. It is editable. Try to change this text.</div>

    </body>
```

Comment: This is a complete guess as what the problem is.  Also having a width and height would not stop the text from wrapping

Comment: add overflow:auto. This will add scroll bars to your div element.